# Promise All Reject Issue

Tags: javascript, promise

I used promise all function for running multiple promises. I'm getting error **Uncaught (in promise) reject**, but here I've used the catch block. I don't know how this it throw the error.

```
function fetch(data) {
  new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    data ? reject('reject') : resolve('resolve')
  })
}

Promise.all([fetch(), fetch('sssssssss')])
 .then(function(data) {
    console.log('all finished',data)
  })
 .catch(function(error) {
   alert('ssssssssssssss')
 })

fetch()
```

Comment: your fetch function doesn't return anything - try `return new Promise.......` if you want to **return** the promise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See below code. hope it will solve your problem.

```
function fetch(data) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    data ? reject('reject') : resolve('resolve')
  })
}

Promise.all([fetch(), fetch('sssssssss')])
 .then(function(data) {
    console.log('all finished',data)
  })
 .catch(function(error) {
   alert('ssssssssssssss')
 })

fetch()
```

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its [long-term value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by describing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.